# How do I run my bash script on Terminator? Or is it even possible?

Tags: terminator

So I have this bash script that when I open in terminal it already inputs the words I want so I don't have to type it in. I was wondering if I can use the same script on Terminator and if I can, how?

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn -noecho bash
expect "$ " 
send "my custom text"
interact
exit
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: How did you run it in gnome terminal?

Comment: You can do this, not sure if it replaces it though... http://www.postimg.org/image/hls2e1lx9 Hope this helps!

Comment: @Seth I saved it as a .sh file then i chmod it to make it executable and i double click it and clicked 'Run in Terminal'

Comment: @Nick what exactly do i do? Hahaha

Comment: just make your layout with the 8 split, and where that textbox is, you put what yu want it to load on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminator, and navigate to the directory your script is stored in.

Then you can run:

```
expect nameOfScript.sh
```

To set terminator as the default terminal use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec terminator
```

To reset the default terminal back to gnome-terminal use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal
```

Comment: I want to double click the .sh file and have it open up in Terminator, is that possible?

Comment: @Jester I think so, I'm investigating as we speak.

Comment: @Jester I've figured out how to set terminator as the default terminal, do you want to do that? Or just make terminator open .sh files?

Comment: I just want the terminator to open the .sh file

Comment: @Jester Ok, I found two options. You can set terminator as the default terminal and then click "run in terminal" or you can set terminator as the default for `.sh` files, which will open terminator instantly on a double click.

Comment: Can you give me the instructions for both please so i can decide for myself what i like better, thanks!! :D

Comment: @Jester My method for making terminator default for only `.sh` files stopped working. I've added instructions for setting terminator as default though. You should then be able to double click it and select "run in terminal"

Comment: Thank you so much man! Can you also give me the instructions to undoing that like if i didn't like it how can i get the terminal back. THANKS AGAIN!!! :D

Comment: @Jester done. I'll keep looking at the other method (with the `.sh`) and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hey man, one problem, it still opens up terminal instead of terminator :/

Comment: @Jester Sorry, wrong commands. Updated.

Comment: I love you dude.

Comment: Hey man, when i pin the .sh file to my task bar it runs in Terminal instead of terminator, do you know why? THanks! :D

Comment: How are you pinning the file to the launcher?

Comment: I just drag it to the panel just like you pin stuff on the task bar on windows 7

Comment: @Jester You don't seem to be using Unity then..